# Como dividir o Contexto em vários arquivos?

Tags: asp.net-core

Estou refatorando um projeto grande que possui cerca de trezentas tabelas usando .Net Core e [Oracle.EntityFrameworkCore](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Oracle.EntityFrameworkCore/)
Com o scaffold ele me gera um ModelContext. Porém ficaria imenso se eu fizesse todas as entidades nesse único ModelContext. Pensei em injetar um contexto na dependência e todos os outros herdariam dele mas o controller não reconheceu.
Por exemplo, criei esse contexto:

```
using System;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata;

namespace webapi.Models
{
    public partial class TesteContext : DbContext
    {
        public TesteContext()
        {
        }
        public TesteContext(DbContextOptions<TesteContext> options)
            : base(options)
        {
        }

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

E esse outro para herdar desse acima:

```
using System;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata;

namespace webapi.Models
{
    public partial class ModelContextImoImovel : TesteContext
    {


    }
}
```

E tentei injetar a dependência assim no Starutp.cs:

```
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            var connectionString = Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");

            services
            .AddEntityFrameworkOracle()
            .AddDbContext<TesteContext>(options => options.UseOracle(connectionString));


>services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
        }
```

Mas na execução ele me retorna

> Unable to resolve service for type 'webapi.Models.ModelContextImoImovel'
> Alguma sugestão? Obrigado.